# Kendo Typescript definition does not suport 'observableHierarchy'

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, typescript, durandal, kendo-treeview

I found the Typescript definition for KendoUI in version 2013.1.319.open-source. I am creating SPA with Durandal + Knockout + Typescript and want to make a treeview with KendoUI but it seems that kendo.observableHierarchy is not supported.

The typescript that comes with the version mentioned above is kendo.web.d.ts. How different it is from kendo.all.d.ts that is written on this page? http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/typescript/overview

And where can we download kendo.all.d.ts? I could not find it from their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "kendo.all.d.ts" comes with the kendo ui full license. That said, you can get a copy from here : http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/typescript-definition-file-problems.aspx

But a) its not up to date, b) Will contain definitions for things that are not a part of kendo opensource.

***Solution**:* 
Fix the missing definitions yourself. If you are having difficulty and want a quick start you can always do:

```
(<any>kendo).observableHierarchy
```

And typescript will not complain.